# How to use measureTextWidth in nextjs 13?

Tags: antd, next.js13

This is how it is if I need to import components, but how do I do it in function?

```
const Pie = dynamic(() => import("@ant-design/charts").then((mod) => mod.Pie), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

I tried

```
const { measureTextWidth } = await import("@ant-design/charts")
 const { width: textWidth, height: textHeight } = measureTextWidth(
    text,
     style
    );
```

but it does not work

Comment: Did you try to add `import {measureTextWidth} from '@ant-design/plots'` outside component (just like you import `React` props)? does it work?

Comment: It works on yarn dev but it will fail on yarn build. Sorry about that, I should’ve probably added that detail in the post

Comment: Try disabling `swcMinify` on `next.config.js`

Comment: I tried and it still didnt work, I still got ReferenceError: document is not defined on yarn build